# How to replace specific bytes at an index in a bytes32?

Tags: solidity

I have a `bytes32` that I plan to pack with 10 `bytes3` at specific indexes without affecting the other bytes already set. So for instance if I had a `bytes3` of `0xABCDEF` into `bytes32` at the index 3, it will go from this:

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  ^0    ^1    ^2    ^3    ^4    ^5    ^6    ^7    ^8    ^9    ^ignore last 4 bits
```

to this:

```
0x000000000000000000ABCDEF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  ^0    ^1    ^2    ^3    ^4    ^5    ^6    ^7    ^8    ^9    ^ignore last 4 bits
```

I believe this could be achieved with some bitwise magic but I'm not too familiar with it. I found [an example that sets individual bits](https://hiddentao.com/archives/2018/12/10/using-bitmaps-for-efficient-solidity-smart-contracts) and tried to tweak it to set more than just individual bits:

```
bytes32 currentBytesGroup;
currentBytesGroup = currentBytesGroup | bytes3(number) << (positionWithinGroup * 24);//3 bytes = 24 bits
```

however this doesn't appear to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
contract ShiftDemo {
    bytes32 public s;

    function execute(bytes3 d, uint256 idx)public {
        s = s | (bytes32(d) >> (idx*8));
    }
}
```

A few thing to note:

- If you shift `bytes3` for more than 24 bits you will get three zero bytes. The shift operators (`<<` and `>>`) don't change the base type. To properly shift you first have to cast to a larger type like `bytes32`.
- `bytesXX` are left aligned, `bytes32(0xAABBCC)` results in `0xAABBCC000000..00`. If you apply `<<` for more than 24 bits you will get zero bytes. You have to use `>>` right shift instead.

Comment: Thank for you answer! It seems to work, but only if the bytes are all zeroes - if there's existing bytes where the data needs to go it doesn't overwrite correctly. I saw in another question in C here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132906/replace-byte-in-32-bit-number they "mask" the bits before writing, i assume that needs to be done here somehow? Also, I have to multiply `idx` by 3 to take into account my chosen indexes are every 3 bytes.

Comment: I've taken what you said and applied it with masking and now it works great for me:
`function replaceBytesAtIndex(bytes32 original, uint position, bytes3 toInsert) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        bytes3 maskBytes = 0xffffff;
        bytes32 mask = bytes32(maskBytes) >> ((position*3) * 8);
        return (~mask & original) | (bytes32(toInsert) >> ((position*3) * 8));
    }`